# Continuous distribution with probability density function $f_X$ question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a continuous distribution with pdf $f_X$ given by:

$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 
0.5+x & 0<x<1 \\ 
0 & otherwise. 
\end{cases}$

I must find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ and also find the distribution function $F_X$ for $X$. Can someone please help me through this question since I have no idea what to do?

EDIT: I can't add comments for some reason but I have the $E(X)$ as $\frac {7}{12}$ and the $Var(X)$ as $\frac {59}{144}$. Is this correct? What do I do in regards to finding the distribution function?

Comment: Recall the definition of expectation, and the definition of variance. Write them out as integrals. Can you find the value of these integrals?

Answer (score 0):

$E\left[X^{n}\right]=\int x^{n}f_{X}\left(x\right)dx$. Work that
out for $n=1,2$ and realize that $\text{Var}\left(X\right)=E\left[X^{2}\right]-E\left[X\right]^{2}$.